# Install Matlab engine in Anaconda Python (Linux)

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda

I'm trying to install `Matlab Engine for Python` on CentOS 7 for Matlab R2016a using anaconda python 3.4.

I executed the following commands:

```
source activate py34 # Default is python 3.5
python setup.py install
```

The output is:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab
creating /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal
copying build/lib/matlab/_internal/mlarray_sequence.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal
copying build/lib/matlab/_internal/__init__.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal
copying build/lib/matlab/_internal/mlarray_utils.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal
copying build/lib/matlab/mlarray.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab
creating /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/engineerror.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/futureresult.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/basefuture.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/__init__.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/enginesession.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/_arch.txt -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/engine/matlabfuture.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine
copying build/lib/matlab/mlexceptions.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab
copying build/lib/matlab/__init__.py -> /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_sequence.py to mlarray_sequence.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_utils.py to mlarray_utils.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/mlarray.py to mlarray.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/engineerror.py to engineerror.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py to futureresult.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py to fevalfuture.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/basefuture.py to basefuture.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py to matlabengine.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/enginesession.py to enginesession.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabfuture.py to matlabfuture.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/mlexceptions.py to mlexceptions.pyc
byte-compiling /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlabengineforpython-R2016a-py2.7.egg-info
```

It somehow install matlab engine into system's python version other than anaconda's `py34` virtual env. I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357739/problems-installing-matlab-engine-for-python-with-anaconda) on OSX and it does work on my mac! Anyone can help with this on CentOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python"
python setup.py install --prefix="installdir"
```

For Unix (OSX10) python2.7, using Anaconda

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/extern/engines/python
python setup.py install --prefix="/Users/user/anaconda/"
```

Here is the Matlab Document:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-matlab-engine-api-for-python-in-nondefault-locations.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's definitely better option:D

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I request you to kindly update your answer with the tip given by [talentcat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6736692/talentcat) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553740/3337089
It's highly useful.

Comment: Also checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560599/3337089)

Answer (score 4):

Just a reminder for those who have multiple virtual envs under the anaconda folder, after doing

`python setup.py install --prefix="/Users/user/anaconda/"`

as prompted by @Leighton, the Matlab engine package is actually installed under the separate

```
anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-package/matlab
```

folder rather than the normal

```
anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-package.
```

So you need to manually move that Matlab folder to the site-package folder your python is using.

If you have multiple virtual envs, move it to the corresponding site-package folder of the virtual env you will run program.

Answer (score 3):

After so many tortures I finally solved this in a simple way. Instead of configure system to use anaconda's python by modifying .bash_profile, you can add an alternative to python command:

```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python ~/anaconda3/envs/py34/bin/python 2
  update-alternatives --display python
  cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/engines/python/
  sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,Im using wsl ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10, MATLAB R2021a and Pycharm.

1. Create conda env

[image]

2. Get the matlab installation folder by typing `matlabroot` in the MATLAB command Window.

> ```
> `ans =
>
>     /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a`
> ```

Now, all input will be typed in the linux shell.

3. Change directory to the matlabroot

> ```
> (base) disusr@disusr:~$ cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a
> ```

4. Check all available conda env via `conda env list`.

   (base) rpb@rpb:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/engines/python$ conda env list

> ```
> base                  *  /home/disusr/anaconda3
>
> ext_env     /home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env
> ```

- Notice the base in the enclosed bracket. This indicate `base` env of conda is currently activated.

5. Activate the `ext_env` by typing

> ```
> conda activate ext_env
> ```

You will notice in terminal, it now looks

> (ext_env)
> disusr@disusr:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/engines/python$

6. Next, install the MATLAB engine by typing

> sudo python setup.py install
> --prefix="/home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env/"

- Notice the double quote enclosing the full dir name of conda directory. The double quote should be there.
- `conda info` should give the full path of the conda `env`.

7. Thanks to @talentcat about the need to move the [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553740/6446053).

In the file manager, navigate to the folder

> ```
> /home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
> ```

[image]

and cut the folder `MATLAB`,

then navigate to the folder

> ```
> /home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
> ```

and paste the folder `MATLAB`

8. Then, open the MATLAB gui by typing `matlab` in the shell

> (ext_env)
> disusr@disusr:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/engines/python$ matlab

9. In the MATLAB `Command Window`, type `pyversion()`, which should print

> > pyversion()

```
   version: '3.8'
executable: '/home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env/bin/python'
   library: '/home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env/lib/libpython3.8.so'
      home: '/home/disusr/anaconda3/envs/ext_env'
  isloaded: 0
```

10. Potential problem

- If the output is as below

> ```
>    version: ''
> executable: ''
>    library: ''
>       home: ''
>   isloaded: 0
> ```

a) Restart MATLAB
b) Make sure, when opening the MATLAB, the conda environment where the MATLAB engine is installed already being activated. Refer step (5). OR, to check section `How to permanently activate the conda environment`.

`***` I have not tried whether opening the MATLAB using `symbolic links` will connect the MATLAB-ENGINE or not. Please comment if you manage to execute this successfully.

Bonus:

## How to permanently activate the conda environment.

In terminal, type

```
nano .bashrc
```

Then add the following line

```
export PATH=”/home/disusr/anaconda3/bin":$PATH"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/disusr/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/nu>
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/disusr/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/disusr/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/disusr/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
source activate ext_env
```

To save the appended string

```
ctl + x
```

and

```
Y
```

Comment: For Install Matlab engine in Anaconda Python (Windows) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70235317/6446053