# Install Matlab engine in Anaconda Python (Windows)

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to install the matlab.engine package for anaconda spyder on windows.

I have tried:

```
cd matlabroot\extern\engines\python
python setup.py install
```

But i get the error: could not create 'build'. Access denied. I've tried searching for answers, but I don't understand them.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try open terminal (cmd.exe) as admin. And more information about the process (if you are using anaconda prompt, cmd, powershell).

Answer (score 1):

For this setup, I am using `Windows 10`, `MATLAB R2020b` and `Pycharm`.

1. Create new Condo environment in Pycharm (add Intepreter)

[image]

2. Sanity check that the `python.exe` exist within the newly create `env`

[image]

3. Add the `C:\Users\author\Anaconda3\envs\integrate_matlabs` in path. On the Windows `Search Bar`, type `Edit the system environment variables` Click the (1)`Environment Variables..`, (2) `Path` which is located under the section `System variables`, (3) `Browse..` and browse to the `C:\Users\author\Anaconda3\envs\integrate_matlabs`.Finally click (4) `OK`.

[image]

4. Start MATLAB and type matlabroot in the command window.  Copy the path returned by matlabroot.

`'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b'`

[image]

5. On search Bar, type `Command prompt`, right click, and select `run as administrator`

[image]

6. On the command prompt, type

6a) `cd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\engines\python`

6c `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\engines\python>python setup.py install`

A long list of log will be displayed. Wait until the line

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\engines\python>
```

which indicate the installation is complete.

7. Restart the MATLAB,
8. Type  `pyversion()` on the Matlab command window which will displayed

[image]

Comment: For Install Matlab engine in Anaconda Python (Linux) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359341/6446053

Answer (score 0):

If you have already built the `matlab.engine` package previously and just want to use it in another environemnt, just navigate to

`matlabroot\extern\engines\python\build\lib`

and copy the `matlab` folder into the `Lib` folder of your environment.